# HTML5 Canvas, create a vertical carousel

Tags: html, canvas, kineticjs

Using KineticJS or pure Canvas is possible to create a vertical carousel like this:
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_vertical.html

I want to build a mobile interface where users can select items from a vertical carousel and drag them around the canvas area to draw shapes and fill in an empty room.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's no reason this would be unfeasible, though what you call a carousel most people refer to as a "palette" in your intended usage.

Comment: There isn't really a question here, can you be more specific? Try using KineticJS for this and post some code in a jsfiddle and others can then help you with more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mobile, you might wanna keep your tech stack low and keep it to only canvas. Mixing canvas elements + other elements sometimes can cause an issue.

We did something very similar recently which I would love to link you to but can't. It used draggable elements in the DOM (not canvas) from jquery and detected where those elements were on the page on release. Since we knew where the canvas was it was possible to determine where the drop occurred.